# How to compute CategoricalCrossentropy using TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to understand the `CategoricalCrossentropy()` loss function in TensorFlow 2.0. When I use

```
tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalCrossentropy(actual, pred)
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Can anyone explain how can it be corrected?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/CategoricalCrossentropy), to compute the cross entropy, use,

```
cce = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalCrossentropy()
# cce.update_state(target, prediction)
cce.update_state([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]])

cce.result().numpy()
# 1.1769392
```

OTOH, if you're trying to compute the cross entropy *loss*, use `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy` instead:

```
cce = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalCrossentropy()
cce([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]]).numpy()
# 1.1769392
```

Comment: @Leevo Isn't that obvious? When computing categorical cross entropy, A has to be one hot. I've just shown you the right usage without going into any more detail about the correctness of your sample data, because I assume that isn't actually what you're working with.